# HPUX top command out put regarding memory explained

Tags: memory, top, hp-ux

While we run top on HP-UX ksh console we can see set of memory related value. Out of that I want to get the total physical memory and free memory.

The output would look like follows on multiple run on same machine

> Memory: 3298168K (2220868K) real, 13870752K (11320292K) virtual, 50204K free
>
> Memory: 3370124K (2268140K) real, 13796928K (11299204K) virtual, 28440K free
>
> Memory: 3375964K (2374688K) real, 13829572K (11486128K) virtual, 22584K free

- On it what is the total memory?
- What is the free memory?
- What is the value in brackets()?

Comment: So you basically were too lazy to type `man top`?

Comment: @schaiba I already check the man command and some google also done. But still no where it is clearly mentioned how to find physical memory usage out of top output. I'm using 3 HP-UX machine all shows free memory as somewhere 50Mb only. But system running without any problem. So I want to know the memory usage by example. Could you please guide me how to find the total and free memory usage in this output?

Answer (score 1):

according to `man top`

> ```
>        Memory Data
>             Reports virtual and real memory used by user processes (with
>             the amount of memory considered "active" in parentheses) and
>             the amount of free memory.
> ```

- Virtual is memory you allocate, real is memory you use.

(e.g. I allocate 10 000 int, but use the first 13 and from 1001 to 1024, my **virtual** would be 10000, and my **real** 37 (13+24)).

Comment: Thanks for the guide. But little clarification needed. according to my example is it having 3298168 Kb of total memory and only 50204Kb of free memory? It would be great if you can help me to find memory utilization from this output.